# How can I know the Jenkins Build Status

Tags: jenkins, build, action

Im actually doing my own Jenkins plugin, and I have a class that extends from `RunListener<Run>`, with the next `onCompleted()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(Run build, TaskListener listener) {
    int number = build.number;
    EnvVars env;
    String name = "";
    try {
        env = build.getEnvironment(listener);
        name = env.get("JOB_NAME") + "-" + env.get("BUILD_NUMBER");
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GraphicAction act = new GraphicAction(name);
    build.getActions().add((Action) act);
}
```

Is there any posibility of executing the last 2 lines only if the build has been successful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jenkins REST API to get the job status:
{JENKINS_URL}/job/{JOB_NAME}/lastBuild/api/json

and then look for value for "status".

[jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins) [rest](/questions/tagged/rest)